# Can't log into Linux Samba share from Windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, networking, samba

Whenever I go to my network shares on windows, I am prompted with a request for username and password on the folder I want to access. Most of the time it won't let me log in with the username and password I set up, but eventually if I do log in, I am just prompted with a window that says "You do not have permission to access `\\ipaddress\destinationfolder` please contact you network admin"

On my Linux side where the share is being hosted I have a `smbpasswd` set for the user, the privileges are all set to `rw` on the folder, and I have the following listed in my `smb.conf` file:

```
[destinationfolder]
path = /place/destinationfolder
valid users = @assigneduser
force group = assigneduser
read only = no
guest ok = yes
browsable = yes
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
```

Additionally all of the `smbstatus` fields turn up blank

Comment: I have found that it is WAY WAY easier to share from the windows side and not the Linux side.  Your problem probably has to do with how you are specifying the windows user name.  Try `<windows share ip address>\<windows share user name>` for your user.  Test the share with another windows box first.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas Unfortunately, the hardware I am using requires Linux to Windows share. Devices are writing data to the Linux host and a Windows computer is logging in remotely to extract the data.